# mongodb find problem

Tags: mongodb

in user_history collection

```
user_name: john
eat : [{food:'apple', timestamp:123}, {food:'cheese', timestamp:80}]

user_name: paul
eat : [{food:'melon', timestamp:125}, {food:'bread', timestamp:60}]

user_name: mattew
eat : [{food:'water', timestamp:90}, {food:'pizza', timestamp:91}]
```

I need to get food which has timestamp over 100

my code:

```
db.user_history.find({"eat.timestamp":{$gte:100}},{"eat.food":1})
```

result:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('......'),'eat':[{food:'apple'},{food:'cheeza'}]},
{'_id': ObjectId('......'),'eat':[{food:'melon'},{food:'bread'}]}
```

result I want to get:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('......'), 'eat':{food:apple}},
{'_id': ObjectId('......'), 'eat':{food:melon}}
```

how could I get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think its possible,see the ticket: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-828.
Looks like this question is [already asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562485/get-particular-element-from-mongodb-array)