# Retrieve elements from MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I've been looking at some StackOverflow cases such as [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562485/get-particular-element-from-mongodb-array?lq=1), but I cannot find an example with a document structure close to this one.

Below is an example of one document within my collection `artistTags`. All documents follow the same structure.

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5500aaeaa7ef65c7460fa3d9"),
  "toptags": {
    "tag": [
      {
        "count": "100",
        "name": "Hip-Hop"
      },
      {
        "count": "97",
        "name": "french rap"
      },
      ...{
        "count": "0",
        "name": "seen live"
      }
    ],
    "@attr": {
      "artist": "113"
    }
  }
}
```

1) How can I `find()` this document using the "artist" value (here "113")?

2) How can I retrieve all "artist" values having a specific "name" value (say "french rap") ?

Comment: 1) `db.collection.find({"toptags.@attr.artist": "113"})`

Comment: thanks ! as you can see I'm a beginner :-), do you want *answer* to win some credits or can I answer myself ?

Comment: That's ok, you can post the solution that worked for you, others may find it useful :)

Comment: You should read the official [getting started guide](https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/shell/) that is very simple to understand and will provide you with this kind of informations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring to [chridam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/122005/chridam) answer here above:

```
db.collection.find({"toptags.@attr.artist": "113"})
```