# Defining a Function to Match document array element to document value in Meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb, meteor

I have been working on a meteor web app. I inserted a document into MongoDB.

```
questionsList.insert({ask: "When was the War of 1812", answer: "1812", possAnsw: ["1811", "1812", "1819", "1820", "1840"]})
```

I am looking to have a function match when a person chooses the correct answer out of the possible answers. The problem is that I am having a hard time accessing one value and matching it to a specific `<li>` tag.

Pseudo-code:

```
if (li.currentTarget == questionList.find({answer: 1}).fetch() {
       $(li.currentTarget).css("background-color", "yellow");
}
```

Essentially, this would highlight only if I clicked the right answer:

```
Template.questions.events({
      'click .answers':function(li) {

        $(li.currentTarget).css('background-color', "yellow").css("width", "fit-content");

      }

    });
```

Right now, it highlights each `<li>` element regardless if it matches the correct answer (i.e. "ask"). The problem is I cannot seem to find how to get the value of the "ask" key and match it to the li.currentTarget.

I have looked at a couple of the following articles to no avail:

[Get particular element from mongoDB array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562485/get-particular-element-from-mongodb-array)

[Retrieve only the queried element in an object array in MongoDB collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection)

Answer (score 0):

if I get your question correctly, basically when user click an answer of question, the server will check if it is correct answer.. so, I think you should query the question not the answer

```
var currentQuestionObject = questionList.find({ask: "When was the war of 1812?"}).fetch()

if (li.currentTarget == currentQuestionObject.answer) {
   $(li.currentTarget).css("background-color", "yellow");
}
```

Comment: I think you're right; the problem is that `currentQuestionObject.answer` isn't returning the value, only "undefined". I wasn't having much luck with this approach. I ultimately separated the answer from the array. I can end up with the right coloration in the background, but the new problem is that no randomization algorithm seems to be working to randomize the `<li>` elements. The problem in short is that the right answer will always be first or last.

Comment: So essentially, I have `<ol id="ordering">

        {{#each question}}
        <p> {{ask}} </p>


        <div class="item" data-value="{{@index}}">

      <li class="answers"> {{answer}} </li>
          <br>
                {{#each wrongAns}}
            <li class="wrong">{{this}}</li>
            <br>

        {{/each}}</div> {{/each}}

    </ol>`